# redshift, how to handle escaped json

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am processing debezium messages like this:

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'educations', 'string') as educations
FROM relevent_debezium_messages limit 10;
```

and it gives me results like this:

```
"[{\""id\"": \""Australian National University\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""Australian National University\""}]"
"[{\""id\"": \""School\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""School\""}]"
"[{\""id\"": \""CPP\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""CPP\""}]"
"[{\""id\"": \""Archbishop McGrath\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""Archbishop McGrath\""}, {\""id\"": \""Swansea University\"", \""type\"": \""\"", \""selected\"": true, \""displayName\"": \""Swansea University\""}]"
```

But I want it like this:

```
'[{"id": "CBS", "type": "", "selected": true, "displayName": "CBS"}]'
```

so I can correct run `JSON_PARSE` like this: `select JSON_PARSE('[{"id": "CBS", "type": "", "selected": true, "displayName": "CBS"}]')`

How do I do this? Is there any elegant way to do this?